# Django website gives an importerror for mixins

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have been given a set of files (Django website) that I am supposed to deploy on a local box and 'support'. First off, I have to say that I have only very basic experience with Django (mostly doing the tutorials and building a simple app myself). Secondly, the files come with no `requirements.txt` or any instructions so I have had to rely on a lot of repetitive trials, which got me to the part that I am able to run the server (`python manage.py runserver`), after installing the dependencies on which the `runserver` command would crash (i.e. `bootstrap_themes`, `Pillow` and `dbbackup`). but as soon as I try to access the website I get the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://ec2-34-252-71-244.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['gts.apps.GtsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap_themes',
 'dbbackup']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  365.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  401.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  395.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/ubuntu/glycoenzymes/GlycoEnzymes/glycoenzymesapp/urls.py" in <module>
  22.     url(r'^gts/', include('gts.urls'    )),
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  33.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/ubuntu/glycoenzymes/GlycoEnzymes/gts/urls.py" in <module>
  7. from . import views
File "/home/ubuntu/glycoenzymes/GlycoEnzymes/gts/views.py" in <module>
  6. from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named mixins
```

The coder that made the original files says that the website runs with no problem on his box and that he is able to install it again without any issues. Therefore, my question is how to find out why it doesn't work on my box (considering that the original coder is rather unresponsive). Specifically, if there is any good way to see what a Django project needs if it doesn't come with a `settings.txt` file or hand-over document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed Django 1.8.7. The auth mixins were [added in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.9/#permission-mixins-for-class-based-views).

When you install Django, you should install the latest point release. For example, you have installed Django `1.8.7`, but the latest point release is `1.8.17`, so you are missing security fixes. If you decide to deploy 1.9.x, note that [security support will end in April 2017](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) when Django 1.11 is released. Django 1.8 was an LTS so will be supported until April 2018.

Comment: That is a good point. However, my question was more aimed at if there was any good way to see what a django project needs if it doesn't come with any requirements.txt file (or a hand over document). Furthermore, as soon as fixing this issue, we go straight away to a new problem `no module named context_processors` and I don't want to chase each error one by one if there is a better way.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that can analyse a Python project and produce a `requirements.txt`. Note that asking for recommendations is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Get the user to run `pip freeze` on their box. That will produce a list of installed packages. You can create a requirements file from that (you may be able to trim some of the packages from it).

Comment: @BasJansen run `pip freeze >> requirements.txt` on a terminal at desired location if you want to list the packages and installed version in your current virtualenv to a `txt` file.